# Flutter listview bottom overflow

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm attempting to create a scrollable listview inside of a container which also contains a static image. However, the listview doesn't appear to be scrollable and I get a "bottom overflow by x pixels" artifact on my app.

[image]

```
  static List<Widget> getClubs() {
    var myClubs = new List<Widget>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      myClubs.add(new Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage:
                new NetworkImage("https://i.imgur.com/p2oUDLD.png"),
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            radius: 34.0,
          )));
    }
    return myClubs;
  }

  final leftSection = new Container(
      color: Color(0xFF212121),
      width: 100,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          new Image.asset(
            'assets/logo.png',
            alignment: Alignment.center,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          new Container(
              child: new ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            children: getClubs(),
          ))
        ],
      ));
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [Expanded](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget or set the height for the Container.

Comment: Yes! Something yet so simple has taken so long to figure out. Thanks.

Comment: @Zander17 +1 that

Answer (score 2):

I would also recommend `Wrap` for anyone running into an issue where a container is sized wrong within the listview, causing an overflow:

```
                          new Container(
                             alignment: Alignment.center,
                             child: Wrap( //the magic
                               children: [
                                 new Container(),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
```

Answer (score 2):

wrap the Column in an Expanded widget:

```
Expanded(
  child: Column(
  ),
),
```

Another way is to wrap the Column in a Flexible widget and specify a flex factor.

```
Flexible(
           flex: 1,
           child: Column(
            children: [
                      
                  ],
               ),
           ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes best way to fix an estimated height is using sizedbox

```
      int heightToBeReduced = 380;

      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - heightToBeReduced,
        child: ListView....
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a Flexible in a Row to control the output of the listview builder

Define the scollController

```
    final _scrollController = ScrollController();
```

Define the ListView builder

```
    ListView builder = ListView.builder(
    itemCount: listPerformance?.length,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return PerformanceCardWidget(performanceView: listPerformance[index]);
    });
```

Define a flexible that outputs the listview builder contents

```
    Row(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
    Flexible(
          flex: 6,
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child: Scrollbar(
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  controller: _scrollController, child: builder))
          )
     ])
```